# MonthName-Year as SSRS parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression

I have dimTime table below:

```
TheYear Fiscalyear  TheMonthName    TheMonth
2022    2022 - 2023 November    11
2022    2022 - 2023 October         10
2022    2022 - 2023 September   9
2023    2022 - 2023 February    2
2023    2022 - 2023 January         1
```

How to implement the MonthName and Year as SSRS parameter and have this in the main dataset? Like below:

Select Month-Year: *January-2023*

Dataset: Select
from Table
where date = *selected MonthYear from the parameter*

This will also goes to same report but the selection is Fiscal year:

*Select Fiscal Year: *2022-2023*

Dataset: Select
from Table
where date = *selected FiscalYear from the parameter*

Im trying to convert it to date but dont know where to start.

Comment: Whats the join key between the transactional table and the date dimension? You set up your parameter to return that key. Then you just filter on that key from the transactional table.

Comment: It's just date from the transactional table. The user wants, that instead of selecting 'From' and 'To' date, they will just select from the parameter drop down for MonthName-Year, and for FiscalYear within the date column values.

Comment: Can you post a sample value that is in the `date` column as well as what the data type is - I can't see your data and it really helps if you are very descriptive. Are the dates in this table always start of month for example? or are they individual dates within the month range?